# Access individual feature properties when running l.esri.find or l.esri.query

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet, leaflet-plugins

Here is what my site looks like: https://brandonlprice.github.io/landrecords/. How can I access the feature properties for a layer when running a find or a query on a layer? I have the the feature.properties.length being displayed in a .innerhtml to show the total count of features returned. I also would like to be able to display the individual attributes for each feature in a layer in a .innerhtml when they are clicked on in the map. The onEachFeature would be one way although I do not know how to link that to the query.run or find.run. How can I do that? Are there any other way to access the individual attributes. My query snippet are below.

Query:

```
function tmqueryFunction() {
     latlng = markerLayer.getLatLng();
     tmbufferResult.clearLayers();
document.getElementById("tractcounts").innerHTML = '';
    if (document.getElementById("tm1").checked == true){
       tmquery.nearby(latlng, distance);
       tmquery.run(function (error, featureCollection, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  tmbufferResult.addData(featureCollection).addTo(map)
  document.getElementById('tractcounts').innerHTML = 'Tract Map Records: ' + 
  featureCollection.features.length;      
  });  
  map.fitBounds(L.geoJSON(featureCollection).getBounds());
});
}
}
```

Comment: When I run your code/site, I get error `markerLayer is not defined` at line 388.

Comment: I am aware. It is a global variable issue. It still works for now. Do you have an idea how I can access the individual feature properties for each layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can access feature properties by iterating through layers/features with `.eachLayer` method. Feature properties are accessible through layer `feature` property.

In your case, if you would want to attach popup with some of the feature properties to each layer/feature, your code could look something like this:

```
function tmqueryFunction() {
  if (!markerLayer) return;
  
  latlng = markerLayer.getLatLng();
  tmbufferResult.clearLayers();
  document.getElementById("tractcounts").innerHTML = '';

  if (!document.getElementById("tm1").checked) return;

  tmquery.nearby(latlng, distance);
  tmquery.run(function (error, featureCollection, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    tmbufferResult.addData(featureCollection).addTo(map)
    document.getElementById('tractcounts').innerHTML = 'Tract Map Records: ' + featureCollection.features.length;  
    tmbufferResult.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(
        'REFERENCE: ' + layer.feature.properties.REFERENCE + '<br>' +
        'SUB_NAME: ' + layer.feature.properties.SUB_NAME);
    });

    map.fitBounds(L.geoJSON(featureCollection).getBounds());
  });
}
```

Here is an example of such popup on your map:

[image]